Identify this TV-show about space / fantasy that takes place in a studio
I'm looking for the name of this SciFi series. I the following:

100-300 people are sent into space in hope of finding a new civilization / or to survive, I cant remember which.
In the first 2-4 episodes, you really think that they are in space but later on you and the characters find out that they are actually inside a big studio looking like a hangar that is operated by a large company that are doing some experiments on the passengers inside the spacecraft.
In the last episode of season 1, you can see a girl who is unnatural and has some kind of superpowers and I believe that the experiments that the company was doing was to find out this girls hidden powers. The girl is a child, by the way.

I think this TV-series only had about 8 episodes and it's name starts with "A", but I can be wrong.
What is the name of this TV-series?

Is there anything else you remember?

I added more info! In the first episodes, you really think that they are in space but later on you find out that the spacecraft that they are in is actually inside a giant studio.

Ascension (2014)

In 1963, the U.S. government launched a covert space mission sending
  hundreds of men, women and children on a century-long voyage aboard
  the starship Ascension to populate a new world. Nearly 50 years into
  the journey, as they approach the point of no return, a mysterious
  murder of a young woman causes the ship’s population to question the
  true nature of their mission.

Source: https://scifanworld.com/tv-series/ascension

So Ascension has the twist you mentioned?
